# Parse complex JSON files "undefined"

Tags: javascript, json

I got "undefined" while trying to Parse this JSON file:

```
 {
"responses": [
    {
      "labelAnnotations": [
        {
          "mid": "/m/01yrx",
          "description": "cat",
          "score": 0.9926739,
          "topicality": 0.9926739
        },
        {
          "mid": "/m/01l7qd",
          "description": "whiskers",
          "score": 0.9639658,
          "topicality": 0.9639658
        },
        {
          "mid": "/m/083jv",
          "description": "white",
          "score": 0.9582038,
          "topicality": 0.9582038
        },
        {
          "mid": "/m/0k0pj",
          "description": "nose",
          "score": 0.9425352,
          "topicality": 0.9425352
        },
        {
          "mid": "/m/06z04",
          "description": "skin",
          "score": 0.92025506,
          "topicality": 0.92025506
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This file is th result from a XMLHttpRequest from the google vision API and This is what i'm doing to print "description" field:

```
e.onload=function(){
  var i= JSON.parse(e.response);
  value = i.responses[0]["description"];
  alert(value);
};
```

Comment: `value = i.responses[0].labelAnnotations[0]["description"];`

Comment: i got Cannot read property '0' of undefined with this line "i.responses.labelAnnotations[0]["description"];"

Comment: I edited the comment while you weren't looking :P

Comment: Thank for the edit working just fine !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"undefined" is coming from the below statement

`value = i.responses[0]["description"];`

as labelAnnotations is an object within an array you will reach description using

`value = i.responses[0].labelAnnotations[0]["description"];`